# Optimizing memory usage - Pandas/Python

Tags: python, pandas, memory-management, out-of-memory

I'm currently working with a data set containing raw text which I should pre-process:

```
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize 
from nltk.stem import SnowballStemmer
from nltk.stem.wordnet import WordNetLemmatizer

stop_words = set(stopwords.words('english'))
stemmer = SnowballStemmer('english')
lemma = WordNetLemmatizer()

from autocorrect import spell

for df in [train_df, test_df]:
    df['comment_text'] = df['comment_text'].apply(lambda x: word_tokenize(str(x)))
    df['comment_text'] = df['comment_text'].apply(lambda x: [lemma.lemmatize(spell(word)) for word in x])
    df['comment_text'] = df['comment_text'].apply(lambda x: ' '.join(x))
```

Including the `spell` function, however, rises the memory usage til a point that I get a "Memory error". This doesn't happen without the usage of such function. I'm wondering if there is a way to optimize this process keeping the `spell` function (the data set has lots of misspelled words).

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't got access to your dataframe so this is a bit speculative, but here goes...

`DataFrame.apply` will run the `lambda` function on the whole column at once, so it is probably holding the progress in memory. Instead, you could convert the lambda function into a pre-defined function and use `DataFrame.map` instead, which applies the function element-wise instead.

```
def spellcheck_string(input_str):
    return [lemma.lemmatize(spell(word)) for word in x]

for df in [train_df, test_df]:
   # ...
    df['comment_text'] = df['comment_text'].map(spellcheck_string)
   # ...
```

Could you give this a try and see if it helps?

Comment: Oh great, didn't know about this! I'll try it out! Thank you.

Comment: The memory is reaching 11 GB  again. 13 now. I tried once and my PC froze.

Comment: How big is your dataset? Approximate number of items in column, and typical size of the ["comment_text"] field? I would love to help based on some dummy data. It may be that operating on the data in batches is the way forwards.

Comment: I'm playing with this dataset: https://www.kaggle.com/c/jigsaw-toxic-comment-classification-challenge. Thank you for you kindness. I'm running the code another time and I can check the lines without interrupt it.

Comment: *cant check the number of lines. My approach now is parallelizing it.

Comment: Hey, Phil. Just to give you a feedback, the problem is the spell method. It really consumes memory. For instance, instead of working with the full df, I got a set of unique words and tried to create a dict of spelling corrections. Somehow looking for the properly spell this methods reachs 11GB for a single word!

Comment: Happy to help, and good that you have been able to narrow down to the `autocorrect.spell` method. I've just done a quick search and it seems that spelling isn't a very well supported area for Python libraries. I hope you're able to make your code deliver what you need.

Answer (score 1):

Anyway, I would work with **dask**, you can divide your dataframe in chunks (divisions) and you can retrieve each part and work with it.

https://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/dataframe.html